# How to add custom option dropdown in Magento Checkout Page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I want to add custom drop down option in Magento Checkout Page.
I am using fire checkout in my Magento Store. 
I am newbie in Magento and not getting where to start. 
I have followed [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/08/20/checkout-add-extra-address-field/)  tutorial but not able to figure out anything. 
Please let me know which files should be updated and how can I store that option value in database also.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks